# Dayspan Vuetify: Add a button inside day cell

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a project based on Dayspan Vuetify library (
https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan-vuetify ).
I don't know how i can add a button inside each day cell. Someone help will be welcome!
[Live Demo](https://clickermonkey.github.io/dayspan-vuetify/example/)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever you want in the template (see the button):

https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan-vuetify-example/blob/master/src/App.vue

```
<template slot="eventTimeTitle" slot-scope="{calendarEvent, details}">
        <div>
          <v-icon class="ds-ev-icon"
            v-if="details.icon"
            size="14"
            :style="{color: details.forecolor}">
            {{ details.icon }}
          </v-icon>
          <v-btn outline @click="doSomething" color="indigo">Button</v-btn>
          <strong class="ds-ev-title">{{ details.title }}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="ds-ev-description">{{ getCalendarTime( calendarEvent ) }}</div>
      </template>
```

Add a method for the click:

```
doSomething(e) {
  console.log(e);
  alert('clicked')
}
```

Comment: Thanks to help me on this. But i cloned https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan-vuetify-example locally and replace "eventTimeTitle" slot with the one you just gave me but nothing happens. I was expected that it add a button on each cell.

Comment: Setup a codepen or somewhere the code can be run online and post the link in your question.